# What is the API for class CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_TriggerData?

Tags: civirules

I only manage to get the value of contactID from my processAction using the variable of class CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_TriggerData using getContactId().

I would like to know if I am able to get ParticipantId or EventId since the rule is triggered when participant status is changed ?

thanks,
j.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the getEntityData? That should give you all data that is avaiable for the entity in the triggerData. The contactId is special as we tend to want to do things with contacts :-)
Does that help?
So an example:

```
$contributionRecur = $triggerData->getEntityData('ContributionRecur');
```

which in your case is likely to become

```
$eventData = $triggerData->getEntityData('Event');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Where do get the API documentation to know what are the calls to use for the classes.

Comment: The documentation there is can be found on the CiviCRM documentation (which is temporarily unavailable so I can not provide you the link :-). There is no documentation of each call. As this is a community extension though, you are quite welcome to create it *grin*

Comment: I have the link...https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+-+how+to+make+your+own